# WPF Drop Shadow Effect color not a valid color

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Im trying to make a drop shadow effect the same color as a AccentColorBrush. The only problem is that it color wont accept the output of AccentColorBrush.

AccentColorBrush is a built in brush for MahApps Metro.

```
<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" 
                  Color="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" 
                  BlurRadius="50"/>
```

'#CC6A00FF' Is not a valid value for property 'Color'

Comment: There is a difference between a Color and a Brush.

Comment: Is there anyway i can convert the value between the two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a `Color` and a `Brush` and the `DropShadowEffect.Color` property can only be set to a `Color`. Try the `AccentColor` resource:

```
<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" BlurRadius="50"/>
```

Comment: That works for the initial value although it is very dim, the problem is that when i change the application color it doesn't change this either

Comment: Even if you replace StaticResource with DynamicResource?

Comment: This works perfectly, ill try to make it brighter as it is very dim but your answer solved my problem. Thank you :)